# Как стилизировать текст максимально близко к макету

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, текст, стилизация

Как стилизовать текст чтоб он выглядел максимально приближено к макету?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#2d2d2d;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align-last: auto;
}
.header {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 30px
}

p {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 33px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 30px
}

h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 33px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 30px
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OnlineShop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <h1 class="header">Как ухаживать за обувью из кожи</h1>
            <p>
                Материала для обуви лучше натуральной кожи все ещё не придумали. Качественную кожу очень приятно носить, 
                она идеально ложится по ноге, в нужных местах немного растягивается. 
                В кожаной обуви, если она соответствует погоде, создаётся хороший микроклимат – ноги не мёрзнут, не потеют,
                и чувствуют себя очень комфортно.
                Неудивительно, что по статистике больше 60% покупателей выбирает обувь именно из гладкой натуральной кожи. 
                Вдобавок кожа практична и не требует трудоёмкого ухода. 
            </p>
            <p>
                Но это совсем не означает, что можно раз в полгода протереть обувь тряпочкой и на этом остановиться. 
                Так же, как кожа лица и тела, материал обуви нуждается в заботе. 
                Регулярный уход надолго продлит срок службы любимой пары и сделает
                её аккуратной и сияющей, словно только что из магазина.
            </p>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>
                    <ul>
                        <li> 
                            На что стоит обратить внимание перед покупкой
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Перед тем, как надеть обувь в превый раз
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Ежедневный уход за кожанной обувью в домашних условиях
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <img src="./img/shous.jpg" alt="Замшевые ботинки">
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        <aside>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>
                    <img src="./img/stambul.png" alt="Реклама туров в Стамбул">
                    <p>Горящие туры в Стамбул от 20 000руб</p>
                    <p>Окунись в настоящую восточную сказку</p>
                </figcaption> 
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>
                    <img src="./img/Duster.png" alt="Реклама внедорожника Renault Duster">
                    <p> Новый Renault Duster</p>
                    <p>Легендарный внедорожник в новом дизайне</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </aside>
        <article>
            <h4>На что стоит обратить внимание перед покупкой</h4>
            <p>
                Подбирайте обувь точно по размеру и полноте. 
                Слишкам тесная обувь черезмерно растягивается 
                и кожа испортится,не говоря уже о дискомфорте. 
                А если модель сидит слишком свободно, то при ходьбе 
                на ней начнут образовываться складки и заломы.
            </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h4>Перед тем, как надеть обувь в превый раз</h4>
            <p>
                Перед первой ноской для новой пары нужно подобрать водо- или грязеоттакивающее средство,
                подхлдящее для натуральной кожи, и обработать кожу в соответсвии с инструкцией. 
                После высыхания - чистить кремом.
            </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h4>Ежедневный уход за кожаной обувью в домашних условиях</h4>
            <p>
                Лучше всего заняться обувью после возвращения домой. 
                Если этого не сделать, то со временем появляются трудновыводимые пятна,
                портится цвет кожи, образуются трещены.
            </p>
            <p>
                После каждого выхода на улицу протирайте обувь сухой салфеткой,
                если на коже только пыль, или вложной тряпкой - в случае сильного
                загрязнения. Начинайте мыть с каблука, затем очистите подошву,после
                этого - материал верха. После мытья нужно как следует протереть пару мягкой тканью,
                чтобы избавить от лишней влаги. Иначе обувь будетсушиться очень долго.
            </p>
            <img src="./img/brush.jpg" alt="средства для чистки обуви">
            <p>
                Второй этап-сушка.
                Ни в коем случае не используйте источники тепла - батарею, 
                обогреватель, фен с горячим воздухом. 
                Да,они сушат быстро, но за это приходит расплата в виде
                задубевшей покоробившейся кожи. Нужно вытащить стельки,
                набить обувь бумагой либо положить внутрь формодержатель
                и сушить при комнатной температуре. Тогда ваши туфли или сапоги 
                надолго сохранят красивую форму
                без заломов. сушка дляться довольно долго, и по этому не 
                рекомендуется носить одну и ту же пару каждый день. 
                Обувь и подкладка должны отдохнуть и расправиться, только тогда вам будет комфортно и тепло.
            </p>
            <p>
                И наконец-крем.
                Сухую и чистую пару нужно обработать кремом, чтобы кожа оставалась 
                эластичной,мягкой и блестящей. Наносите крем тоненьким слоем с помощью
                обувной щетки и аккуратно распределите по всейповерхности
                Затем через несколько часов, когда крем впитается, сотрите остатки сухой салфеткой
                отпалируйте кожу мягкой тряпочкой.<br>
                Крем подбирается точно в цвет обуви, поэтому стоит задуматься
                еще перед покупкой, каким уходовым средством вы будете пользоваться.<br>
                В магазине легко подобрать черный, коричневый и самый универсальный-
                бесцветный крем, есть и другие цвета, где бывает сложно найти нужный оттенок.<br>
                По мере необходимости дополнительно обрабатывайте пару водотталкивающими спреями
            </p>
        </article>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо подключить соответствующие шрифты в проект. Название шрифта всегда должно быть прописано в макете. Если шрифт бесплатный, то сделать это можно через https://fonts.google.com/

Если авторские, то нужно запросить их у дизайнера макета, или, возможно где-то удастся их скачать и подключить напрямую в проект к исходным файлам

Comment: `где-то удастся их скачать и подключить напрямую в проект` - если проект коммерческий, то забудьте об этом, только покупка, только там где они продаются (для этого есть менеджеры на проекте, они этим занимаются). Опять же, если шрифт не распространяется бесплатно.

Comment: Ну, на сервисе от гугл есть не все бесплатные шрифты)

Я думаю тут больше в ученических целях макет

Comment: Нет проект не коммерческий. Суть задания стилизовать текст, пока без подключения шрифтов так как это следующий урок. Я хотела бы узнать как сделать так чтоб текст выглядел так же аккуратно по абзацам с прижатым заголовком как на макете.